# C# OpenGL how to remove transparent render?

Tags: c#, opengl

how to make the behind render become solid like top one?? i dont know why, 
this is what i have done so far

```
        public Form1()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();

                    opengldraw.InitializeContexts();
                    width = opengldraw.Width;
                    height = opengldraw.Height;
                    Gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
                    Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_PROJECTION);
                    Gl.glLoadIdentity();
                    Glu.gluPerspective(45.0f, (double)width / (double)height, 0.01f, 5000.0f);

                    Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
                    Gl.glHint(Gl.GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, Gl.GL_DONT_CARE);
    }

 private void simpleOpenGlControl1_Paint_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {



                Gl.glTranslated(0, 0, -120);
                Gl.glPushMatrix();
                Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_MODELVIEW);
                Gl.glLoadIdentity();
                Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | Gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
                Gl.glClearDepth(6f);
                Gl.glLineWidth(4);
                Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_LINES);
                Gl.glColor3f(1, 0, 0);

                Gl.glVertex3f(-30, -30, -30);
                Gl.glVertex3f(80, -30, -30);

                Gl.glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
                Gl.glVertex3f(-30, -30, -30);
                Gl.glVertex3f(-30, 80, -30);


                Gl.glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
                Gl.glVertex3f(-30, -30, -30);
                Gl.glVertex3f(-30, -30, 80);

                Gl.glEnd();
                pitch = System.Convert.ToUInt64(DataSensor[7]);
                roll = System.Convert.ToUInt64(DataSensor[8]);
                yaw = System.Convert.ToUInt64(DataSensor[9]);

                Gl.glRotatef(90, 0, 0, 1);
                Gl.glRotatef(pitch, -1, 0, 0);
                Gl.glRotatef(roll, 0, 1, 0);
                Gl.glRotatef(-yaw, 0, 0, 1);
                Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_TRIANGLES);
                Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | Gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
                Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
                Gl.glHint(Gl.GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, Gl.GL_DONT_CARE);
                //Nose
                for (iogl = 0; (iogl <= 360); iogl = (iogl + 3))
                {
                    Gl.glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
                    Gl.glVertex3f(4 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 4 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 25);
                    Gl.glVertex3f(4 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 20)), 4 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 20)), 25);
                    Gl.glVertex3f(0, 0, 35);

                }
                Gl.glEnd();
                Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
                for (iogl = 0; (iogl <= 359); iogl++)
                {
                    //Tabung
                    Gl.glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
                    Gl.glVertex3f(4 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 4 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 25);
                    Gl.glVertex3f(4 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 30)), 4 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 30)), 25);
                    Gl.glVertex3f(4 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 4 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 6);
                    Gl.glVertex3f(4 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 30)), 4 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 30)), 6);

                }
                Gl.glEnd();


                Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
                for (iogl = 0; (iogl <= 359); iogl++)
                {
                    //Merah Tengah
                    Gl.glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
                    Gl.glVertex3f(4 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 4 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 6);
                    Gl.glVertex3f(4 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 30)), 3 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 30)), 6);

                    Gl.glVertex3f(3 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), (3) * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 3);
                    Gl.glVertex3f(3 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 20)), (3) * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 20)), 3);


                }
                Gl.glEnd();

                Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_QUADS);
                for (iogl = 0; (iogl <= 359); iogl++)
                {
                    //PUTIH Belakang
                    Gl.glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
                    Gl.glVertex3f(3 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 3 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 3);
                    Gl.glVertex3f(3 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 20)), 3 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 20)), 3);
                    Gl.glVertex3f(3 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 3 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), -20);
                    Gl.glVertex3f(3 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 20)), 3 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 20)), -20);
                }
                Gl.glEnd();



                Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_POLYGON);
                for (iogl = 0; (iogl <= 359); iogl++)
                {
                    //putih alas Belakang
                    Gl.glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
                    Gl.glVertex3f(3.5f * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 3.5f * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), -20);
                    Gl.glVertex3f(3.5f * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 20)), 3.5f * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * iogl + 20), -20);
                    Gl.glVertex3f(3.5f * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 3.5f * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), -25);
                    Gl.glVertex3f(3.5f * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * (iogl + 20)), 3.5f * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * iogl + 20), -25);
                }
                Gl.glEnd();


                Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_POLYGON);
                for (iogl = 0; (iogl <= 360); iogl = (iogl + 90))
                {
                    Gl.glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
                    Gl.glVertex3f(0, 0, -25);
                    Gl.glVertex3f(0, 10 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), -17);
                    Gl.glVertex3f(10 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 0, -25);
                    Gl.glVertex3f(0, 0, -25);
                    Gl.glVertex3f(10 * (float)Math.Cos(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), 0, -17);
                    Gl.glVertex3f(0, 10 * (float)Math.Sin(Math.PI / 180 * iogl), -25);
                }
                Gl.glEnd();

                Gl.glLineWidth(3);

                Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_LINES);

                Gl.glColor3f(1, 0, 0);

                Gl.glVertex3f(-20, 0, 0);
                Gl.glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);

                Gl.glColor3f(0, 0, 1);

                Gl.glVertex3f(0, 20, 0);
                Gl.glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);

                Gl.glColor3f(0, 1, 0);

                Gl.glVertex3f(0, 0, 40);
                Gl.glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
                Gl.glEnd();

                Gl.glFlush();
                Gl.glPopMatrix();


            }
            catch
            {
                return;
            }
        }
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

I want the back render is solid as up render, i want remove transparency. what should i add to code?

Comment: `Gl.glClearDepth(6f);` might be a cause

Comment: i already remove, with 6f or without it the result is same

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the pixelformat for your OpenGL window actually has a depth component. Just enabling the depth test (which you did) does not suffice, it also needs something to test against.

Comment: @MuhKhoirul: As I already wrote: Just enabling the test is not enough. You also need a depth *buffer*. To get one, you must request one when setting the pixelformat. This happens somewhere in `InitializeComponent` or `InitializeContext`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is from:

```
            Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
            Gl.glHint(Gl.GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, Gl.GL_DONT_CARE);
```

You may need to enable gl blend too or remove the antialiasing functions. This article might be helpful:

http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~paragc/teaching/2009/cs475/notes/antialiasing_sumair.pdf